# codeql CLI lgtm.yml: how to customize javascript extraction?

Tags: javascript, semmle-ql, codeql

I can use an lgtm.yml file to [customize the javascript extractor](https://lgtm.com/help/lgtm/javascript-extraction#customizing-javascript-extraction) when building a database with LGTM.com, but how do I provide these customizations to the codeql CLI?

Specifically, I want to include a directory that the extractor excludes by default (node_modules).

Here is my lgtm.yml file:

```
extraction:
  javascript:
    index:
      include:
        - node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Supporting this is a work in progress. However in the meantime, including directories that are excluded by default can be enabled by setting the following environment variable before creating the database:

`export LGTM_INDEX_FILTERS='include:/'`

I will update the answer when better support is added.